Cannot identify compile error in testbench
I am learning how to code a UVM testbench, and I am encountering this compile error that I can't understand.
Error message:
interface i2c_interface(
|
xmvlog: \*W,NONAIF (i2c_interface.sv,1|22): Non Ansi Interface port declaration seen - Not official SystemVerilog syntax - \[SystemVerilog\].
interface i2c_interface(
|
xmvlog: \*E,EXPSMC (i2c_interface.sv,1|23): expecting a semicolon (';') \[12.3.2(IEEE)\].
);
|
xmvlog: \*E,EXPSMC (i2c_interface.sv,3|2): expecting a semicolon (';') \[3.2.2(IEEE)\].
endinterface
|
xmvlog: \*E,EXPENM (i2c_interface.sv,16|11): expecting the keyword 'endmodule' \[12.1(IEEE)\].

I tried rewriting code, but error is still there
interface i2c_interface( input logic clk);

logic a;
logic b;
logic c;
logic [7:0] adr, data;

endinterface


The code compiles without errors on Cadence on EDAPlayground.  Perhaps there is a problem with your version of Cadence.  For example, maybe you are using an older version of the simulator which has a bug.  If that is the case, you need to update to a newer version of the simulator software.
If you try to compile only this code (as I have done on EDAPlayground), and the errors go away, perhaps there is a syntax error in other code that you are compiling with this interface code.  Look at the compile order of all the files compiled before this interface.  Try to isolate the problem to one file.
